# Display tags as multiple select

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, twig

I follow this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.

So, tags displayed as group of textareas, but i need display tags as HTML 'select' element with 'multiple' attribute for saving 'Task'-object including selected 'Tags' later.

Maybe, symfony have a 'black magic' converter from 'tags' entity to form and vice versa. I don't know. But, maybe, i found a wrong way for doing that. Somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the tutorial, you just need to change your `buildForm` method on the `TagType` class, so that the `name` field becomes a `choice` type instead of a (guessed) `textarea`.

Replace :

```
$builder->add('name');
```

By :

```
$builder->add('name', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
       'valueA' => 'labelA',
       'valueB' => 'labelB',
       'valueC' => 'labelC',
       'valueD' => 'labelD',
       // ...
    ),
    'multiple' => true,
);
```

And if your choice list is dynamic, a good practice is to declare your [form type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-cookbook-form-field-service).

Some more info about the `choice` field type are [documented here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html).